# Delphi ADO: save DBEdit changes

Tags: excel, delphi, ado, delphi-xe5

I opened Excel table using ADO (though it is probably the same as any other database: adoconnection, adotable, datasource) and display it in ReadOnly DBGrid.
And I have DBEdit to edit some value in currently selected row.

But how to save it? I tried adotable.Post on FormClose but it throws error that "dataset not in edit or insert mode".

Do I need to call adotable.Edit in DBEdit OnEnter and Post OnExit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Post` is automatically called when the user navigates to another record.

The only time you need to call `Post` is if the currently selected record has pending changes at the time you close the form.

But even then, you don't have to call `Post` explicitly: there's a helper function `CheckBrowseMode` you can use instead. If the data set is in edit mode, `CheckBrowseMode` checks if there are any modifications. If not, it cancels the edit, otherwise, it posts those changes. `CheckBrowseMode` won't raise any exception if the data set is already not in edit mode, only if the data set is closed (which shouldn't be possible in your case).

Comment: Oh, yes, looks like it works without Edit/Post. I didn't notice it because when I first tried it I had another problem (I copy the Excel file to bin folder using build events and it was overwriting it each time).